# Accessing suggests in jquery autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-autocomplete

I've attached an autocomplete function to a text input field in an html form. I can handle when the user selects something in the suggest box and it all works fine. I use "suggest" as source.

My problem is that I want to handle the case when the user has entered a few characters and then just hits enter without selecting any of the suggests. I would like to treat this case as if though the user had selected the first suggest. However I can't figure out how I can access the suggests. Is there a way to do that? I need to access the "value" of the suggest. The "label" is not enough.

```
$(myInputField).autocomplete({
 source : "suggest",
 focus : onFocus,
 select : onSelect
});
```

Comment: I don't know how to help in this situation but it will definitely help others if you indicate which jQuery auto suggest library you're using (there's quite a few!)

Comment: I am using jqueryui/1.9.2 for this

Answer (score 0):

You can use `autoFocus: true` so the first item is always on focus.

Check the [autocomplete documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-autoFocus).

Comment: Thanks, that probably solves my problem. But still would be nice to be able to access the suggests.

Comment: Check the [search](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-search) event. It might help you.